# Why sometimes githubusercontent makes image links into markdown format, not html?

Tags: html, image, github, markdown

I usually add my image on github blog by copying the locally saved image into
github code editor.

Then it makes a image's link, it usually saved into form of HTML.
but sometimes it makes MD(markdown) format, not HTML.

What is the condition of image link creation?
I want to know what determines the format of the image's link

I made 2 different images, and copied them into same github code editor.
then it returns 2 different image link, but the formats are different, too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZG9I.png)